# NSPredicate and BEGINSWITH with CloudKit : Field value type mismatch

Tags: ios, sql, nspredicate, cloudkit

I have a table "Store" with the attributes "name" of type String (indexes checked for sort query and search).
I want to execute a SQL like query to find all stores with name beginning with a substring.

So I tried this predicate :

```
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY name BEGINSWITH %@",substring];

CKQuery *query = [[CKQuery alloc]initWithRecordType:@"Store" predicate:pred];

CKQueryOperation *queryOperation = [[CKQueryOperation alloc] initWithQuery:query];

queryOperation.desiredKeys = @[@"name",@"category"];

NSMutableArray *results = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

queryOperation.recordFetchedBlock = ^(CKRecord *record) {
    [results addObject:record];
};
queryOperation.queryCompletionBlock = ^(CKQueryCursor *cursor, NSError *error) {
   //my own code
}
[publicDatabase addOperation:queryOperation];
```

I have this error :

```
<CKError 0x1887a540: "Invalid Arguments" (12/1009); "Field value type mismatch in query predicate for field 'name'"> for query : <CKQuery: 0x18882650; recordType=Store, predicate=ANY name BEGINSWITH "mysubstring">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you need to get rid of the "ANY".

> The ANY and SOME aggregate operators may be combined with the IN and
>   CONTAINS operators to perform list membership tests.

So ANY is for lists (Arrays). Since 'name' is a String, it is not a list, hence the mismatch error: "Field value type mismatch in query predicate for field 'name'"

Comment: Ok thanks, but how can I perform a query to find all the stores with "name" or "category" beginning with my "substring" ?

Comment: @John I'm not sure if you can do it directly. You could try a full text search as another answer suggests, or you could create a new field that is an Array of Strings. Then you could use ANY: "ANY searchableFields BEGINSWITH %@", where searchableFields is a new field in your record that is an array with two elements: name and category.

Answer (score 1):

Wild guess...try:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY {'name','category'} BEGINSWITH %@",substring];
```

That may be an incorrect reversal of key/value but it might work.

Comment: Did it work for you ? because I have this error : *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CKException', reason: 'Unexpected expression: ANY {"name", "category"} BEGINSWITH "mysubstring"'

Comment: If I use [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY name BEGINSWITH 'mysubstring'"] it returns no error with performQuery but no record, and if I use it with CKQueryOperation it returns an error : <CKError 0x813f9230: "Invalid Arguments" (12/1009); "Field value type mismatch in query predicate for field 'name'"> for query : <CKQuery: 0x7f218dd0; recordType=Store, predicate=ANY name BEGINSWITH "mysubstring">

Comment: I simplified the question and opened a bounty to solve the CKError.

Answer (score 1):

A completely different approach would be to create a third field called "nameAndCategory", append the two strings and add them to the field.  Then figure out how to do the full text search (tokenized string search) with the predicate:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self contains '%@'",substring];
```

or

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"self contains '%@'",substring];
```

But perhaps the only sure approach is to do two searches and combine the results.

Comment: I simplified the question and opened a bounty to solve the CKError.